# Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: failed to get shared config profile, <profile>

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In my `main.tf` file I have:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}
```

When I run `terraform plan`, I am getting the error below:

```
Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: failed to get shared config profile, terragrunt
 
   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
   on provider.tf line 2, in provider "aws":
    2: provider "aws" {
```

In my case, I'm not using `terragrunt` in the project at all, purely `terraform` and the error message isn't helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

My `AWS_PROFILE` env variable was set to `terragrunt`. And because my `~/.aws/credentials` file didn't have a profile for terragrunt, I was getting the error. I had to set it to an existing profile and my problem was fixed.

**Context:**

The `shared config profile` terraform is talking about has to do with the `provider.profile` variable in `main.tf`, `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable, and the `~/.aws/credentials` file. In that order of prescedence.

If your `~/.aws/credentials` doesn't have a default profile, then you must point to it explicitly. For example, if it looks like below:

```
[https://sso.jumpcloud.com/saml2/aws]
aws_access_key_id        = <example-id>
aws_secret_access_key    = <example-key>
```

Then you have to either

1. run `export AWS_PROFILE=https://sso.jumpcloud.com/saml2/aws`

or

2. manually specify the `profile` in your `main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
  profile = "https://sso.jumpcloud.com/saml2/aws"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your issue, but I had a similar issue when using "terraform cloud" as the backend.

No matter how much I tried with this config as provider, I could not get `terraform plan` to work.

```html
# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"  
}
```

> Error: failed to get shared config profile, default

I did find the cause to the issue here:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/error-configuring-terraform-aws-provider-failed-to-get-shared-config-profile/45500

From the explanation:

> Terraform is running in a remote server which has no access to the files on your local computer except for the content of your current working directory, which Terraform CLI uploads to Terraform Cloud to allow running the operation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows:

```
provider "aws" {
   region                  = "us-east-1"
   shared_credentials_files  = ["C:/Users/johnny/.aws/credentials"]
   profile                 = "johnny" 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the "profile" in the provider block in your provider.tf file (or where ever you stored your provider block) and it will work.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. There are valid use cases when a specific AWS profile needs to be used when configuring the AWS provider.